# true/false switch toggling back to zero

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

So I tried making a script, that switches the value of a boolean between true and false. For some reason, every time I press the connected button, the boolean value goes to one, but then immediately back to zero

```
bool on = false;

if(digitalRead(inputOn) == HIGH && on == false){
     on = true; 
     digitalWrite(outputLedGreen6, HIGH);
     Serial.print("OnStatus");
     Serial.println(on);
     delay(500);

  } else if(digitalRead(inputOn) == HIGH){
    on = false;
    digitalWrite(outputLedGreen6, LOW);
    Serial.print("OnStatus");
    Serial.println(on);
    delay(500);

  }
```

Comment: Change the second `Serial.print("OnStatus")` to `Serial.print("OnStatus1");` and show the output.

Comment: That does nothing, it literally just changes the Serial output from 0 to 10

Comment: So `Serial.print("OnStatus")` prints nothing?? Are you sure the code you show here is the code you run? _"it literally just changes the Serial output from 0 to 10"_ that sounds like a loop which is not at all what your program does.

Comment: Please show the whole function containing you code.

Comment: Changing the code in your question after answers or comments were given should be avoided. It makes them useless and the authors wasted there time. Please don't do this!

Comment: I changed the code so the next person having the same problem doesn't have to search through this whole post

Comment: @Jabberwocky changing "Serial.print("OnStatus")" to "Serial.print("OnStatus1")" just changes the output on the Serial monitor from 0, what the value of a false boolean is, to 10, but the value of the boolean stays the same. That really doesn't change anything to what the program does

Comment: @Anes no it doesn't but, the outcome might help us to investigate what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool on = false;

if(digitalRead(inputOn) == HIGH && on == false){
     on = true; 
     digitalWrite(outputLedGreen6, HIGH);
     Serial.print("OnStatus");
     Serial.println(on);
     delay(500);

  } 
  else if(digitalRead(inputOn) == HIGH ){ //CHANGE THIS LINE HERE
  //In the question, there was no else statement. Only 2 ifs. So whenever the first if statement executed, the second would also execute.

    on = false;
    digitalWrite(outputLedGreen6, LOW);
    Serial.print("OnStatus");
    Serial.println(on);
    delay(500);

  }
```

Comment: You needed to add an else statement. Whenever the first condition is true, the second is also true.

Comment: I tried it with an "else if", it's still not working

Comment: @Anes Could it be possible the delay was too small? Try increasing the delay to 5000 and check if it still switches back to off

Comment: It does the same, but with more delay

Comment: @Anes What happens if the boolean is initialized to true instead of false in the beginning?

Comment: It does the same, it's inverted the first time, but after that exactly the same

Comment: @Anes Did you write the line `bool on=false` in the loop part of the code instead of making it a global variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210750/discussion-between-abhay-aravinda-and-anes).

Comment: I fixed the problem. When I was declaring the pin modes I put the button to input (like it is supposed to be). When I changed it to output, it started working for some reason. I really don't understand how or why it fixed the problem, but it did

Comment: Answers that only contain code without any explanation are not considered good answers. Instead of adding comments providing missing explanation, you should put it into your answer.

Comment: @Gerhardh got it